# Use efficient CSS selectors

Tags: css, css-sprites

According to PageSpeed, my new css sprites navigation is not using efficient CSS selectors.

Could someone show me know what I am doing wrong?

```
Very inefficient rules (good to fix on any page):
ul.navmenu li a    Tag key with 2 descendant selectors and Class overly qualified with tag
ul.navmenu li.home a    Tag key with 2 descendant selectors and Class overly qualified with tag and Class overly qualified with tag
ul.navmenu li.home a:hover    Tag key with 2 descendant selectors and Class overly qualified with tag and Class overly qualified with tag
```

My CSS :

```
ul.navmenu li a { display: block; background: url('/styles/pc-nav-sprite.png'); }
ul.navmenu li.home a { background-position: 0 -486px; width: 187px; height: 24px; margin-top: 16px;}
ul.navmenu li.home a:hover { background-position: 0 -511px; width: 187px; height: 24px; }
```

HTML :

```
<ul class="navmenu">
<li class="home"><a class="selected" title="Home"></a></li>
<li class="forum"><a href="/forum/" title="Forum"><span class="displace">Forum</span></a></li>
...
...
</ul>
```

I'd appreciate any assistance with this. Thanks.

Comment: Read the warning messages. Your selectors are more-specific than is strictly necessary.

Comment: That's not a "sprite" problem. Leave it as it is, or at least remove the tag name (eg. `ul.navmenu li.home a` -> `.navmenu .home a`). But for me it's good as it is.

Comment: It's **impossible** to know what's efficient (or what will even *work*) without seeing the HTML code... Can you please post it? Also specify if you are open to altering the HTML source.

Comment: Ok, i've edited the post with html code

Comment: FYI. You can remove `width: 187px; height: 24px;` from `ul.navmenu li.home a:hover`.

Comment: You don't need to worry about this. It's not a big deal.

Answer (score -1):

If you aren't using `navmenu` for anything other than a `ul`, you don't need the `ul`. In fact at a wild guess I'd say there's only one of them in which case you can use an ID and `#navmenu`.

You can improve efficiency slightly by using `>` between selectors, because that way it only has to search down one layer instead of a potentially infinite number.

As for the `li.home`, you can probably safely assume that any direct child of a `ul` will be an `li`, so that part's redundant.

Final selectors:

```
#navmenu > li > a
#navmenu > .home > a
#navmenu > .home > a:hover
```